# Notation to express that set is a relation on certain sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there any specific notation to express that a set R is a relation between X and Y, or a relation on Z?

I currently express that as R $\subseteq$ X x Y and R $\subseteq$ Z x Z in terms of subset, or as $\forall$(x, y) $\in$ R((x, y) $\in$ X x Y) and $\forall$(x, y) $\in$ R((x, y) $\in$ Z x Z) with universal quantifiers (which can be simplified to the subset notation mentioned before).

Does such notation exist?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other such notation *in common use* that you can rely on a random reader understanding without explaining it specifically.

(You can always define your own notation, of course -- but given that $R\subseteq X\times Y$ is short and to the point, it would be debatable whether it makes anything more readable).